# parse.com Push Notifications with advanced Targeting

Tags: javascript, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, parse-platform

I am trying to implement the advanced push targeting from cloud code (background job) using [parse.com](https://parse.com/) service. I have added the day as a field in the Installation object.

[image]

I made it work if I have only one condition, i.e. day equals 1, using following snippet

```
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.equalTo("day",1);

Parse.Push.send({
      where: pushQuery,
      data: {
      "content-available" : "1",
      alert : "Message day 1!",
      sound : "default"
   }}, {
       success: function() {
   // Push was successful
   },
       error: function(error) {
       // Handle error
   }}).then(function() {
       // Set the job's success status
       status.success("Job finished successfully.");
   }, function(error) {
       // Set the job's error status
       status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
   });
```

**Reference:** [Push Notification Java Script guide](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-queries/JavaScript)

My next step is sending notifications to 20 queries (0 <= day < 20) and for each query send message according to day number. Calling function 20 times seems to me ugly, may I anyhow iterate, calling each time in loop Parse.Push.send function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem using [Parse.Promise.when(promises)](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Promise.html#.when)

**Promises** are a little bit magical, in that they let you chain them without nesting. If a callback for a promise returns a new promise, then the first one will not be resolved until the second one is. This lets you perform multiple actions without incurring the pyramid code you would get with callbacks.

```
function scheduleWordsForDay(day)
{
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.equalTo("day",day);
    pushQuery.exists("deviceToken");

    var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    Parse.Push.send({
          where: pushQuery,
          data: {
          alert : "word" + day
    }}, { success: function() {
          // Push was successful
        },
          error: function(error) {

        }}).then (function(result){
          //Marks this promise as fulfilled, 
          //firing any callbacks waiting on it.
          promise.resolve(result);
        }, function(error) {
          //Marks this promise as fulfilled, 
          //firing any callbacks waiting on it.
          promise.reject(error);
        });
    return promise;
}

Parse.Cloud.job("scheduleWordNotification", function(request, status)
{
  var promiseArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var promise = scheduleWordsForDay(i);
        promiseArray.push(promise);
  }
  //Returns a new promise that is 
  //fulfilled when all of the input promises are resolved.          
  Parse.Promise.when(promiseArray).then(function(result) {
     console.log("success promise!!")
     status.success("success promise!!");
  }, function(error) {
     console.error("Promise Error: " + error.message);
     status.error(error);
  });
});
```